# Desktop Sharing enabled, vino-server not listening

Tags: vnc

I have 2 machines both running Ubuntu 16.04.3 with the Unity desktop environment.

I enabled *Desktop Sharing*, and disabled *Require Encryption*.
I am able to connect to and use desktop on Machine-A with TightVNC.
Machine-B fails with this message:

```
...target machine actively refused it.
```

`netstat` shows `vino-server` listening on Machine-A.
Not listening on Machine-B.

I can enable `vino-server` by running `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server` and then successfully connect. I need to do this locally. Command does not work over remote SSH session.

The configuration is the same on both machines. Why does `vino-server` not start on one of them?

Added /usr/lib/vino/vino-server to Startup Applications, vino-server is now starting when I login locally. I tried this before without success. Possibly I entered the path wrong previously.

However, I would like vino-server to auto start without the need of me logging in locally first.

Rebooted and connected via SSH, ran /usr/lib/vino/vino-server and got:
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Cannot open display:

Added /usr/lib/vino/vino-server to rc.local, no change.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you turn off the firewall with gufw?

Comment: I have always had to add vino-server into the autostart list manually.

Comment: @heynnema - Firewall isn't the problem. vino-server does not start. Once I manually start vino-server I can connect.

Comment: @Organic Marble - I tried adding /usr/lib/vino/vino-server to autostart, but no difference. Still needed to start vino-server manually.

Comment: In `terminal`, before manually starting vino-server, do `systemctl status` and look for any services that failed to start.

Comment: @heynnema - I was finally able to get vino-server to start automatically when I log in locally. Added /usr/lib/vino/vino-server to Startup Applications. Did not need to do this on the other machine, but it works. i had tried this previously but did not work.

So now my question is, how can I auto start vino-server after reboot without needing to login locally first?
Added /usr/lib/vino/vino-server to rc.local, does not start after reboot.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best answer, but it may work for you. Place your vino start string in `/etc/rc.local` (gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local), remove it from Startup Applications, and reboot. If that works for you, let me know, and I'll put it into an quickie answer that you can accept. Thanks.

Comment: Added /usr/lib/vino/vino-server to rc.local. Did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Could never get vino-server to start on boot, only when I login locally. Installed x11vnc and added systemd script. Able to VNC from Windows 10 using TightVNC to the Ubuntu box after a reboot and no local login. x11vnc presents the Unity desktop, so no need to install any alternative desktop environment.